# How to work with objectARX 2012

Tags: c#, printing, dwg, objectarx

I want to print a .dwg file to printer in my c# application by ObjectARX classes and methods but i am too beginner in ObjectARX.
Which class and methods should i use?Is there any way else to do this?

Comment: Are you creating a standalone application or an addin? You mention ObjectARX, but that technology is for writing C++ addins.

Comment: @Joel,my application is a working in a network.Did you mean i can not use ObjectARX in c#?so how can i access to autocad software and work with dwg files?

Comment: There are .Net bindings to ObjectARX. What you get is a dll that will run inside AutoCAD as an in-process assembly. If you need to automate AutoCAD from outside, as in running a separate exe, then you would need to investigate using AutoCAD through COM/Active-X. Or perhaps writing a script that you can launch AutoCAD with.

Answer (score 0):

[Develop Guide](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/index.html),hope to help you

Comment: It really helps if you provide a description as well instead of just a link!